# Can i add numeric value to existing numeric value in Mongodb by using update method

Tags: javascript, mongodb

If i have a mongodb collection named Posts with document like following:

```
{
    _id: 11111,
    time:40
}
```

how can i add numeric value to the value 'time' on the fly using .update method?
resulting with the following:

```
{
    _id: 11111,
    time:50
}
```

I was hoping something like:

```
Posts.update(this._id, {
    $set: {time:{time+10}}
});
```

which don't seem to work. Is this even possible?  any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

See [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)

```
Posts.update({
    _id: this._id
}, {
    $inc: {
        time: 10
    }
});
```